# how to ExportExcel data with angular typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

in my project i have a table with information (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumbre, Age, Date). i create an function making me to export file excel but i don't want to export all the data i need just to export (FirstName, LastName, Age).

this is what i do

**excel.html :**

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    <table id="excel-table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>PhoneNumber</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor='let excel of excels'>
                <td>{{excel.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{excel.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{excel.PhoneNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{excel.Age}}</td>
                <td>{{excel.Date}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="exportexcel()">ExportExcel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**excel.ts :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-execls',
  templateUrl: './execls.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./execls.component.css']
})
export class RegionsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private fb: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  fileName = 'ExcelFile.xlsx';

  exportexcel(): void {
    let element = document.getElementById('excel-table');
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you are using sheetJS based on your code, and looking at the documentation, there is not a way to pass in columns you wish to display. https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities/#html-table-input. One option is to create another table with just the columns you want to display, but set that table to `hidden`.

```
<table id="excel-table-to-export" class="table" hidden>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let excel of excels'>
            <td>{{excel.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{excel.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{excel.Age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```